# Unable to show Highcharts graph with in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I was trying to bind data to [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) & display a column chart on webpage.
Below given jQuery AJAX method to call controller's action

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getChartData", "Default")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (resData) {
            let dataArray = new Array();
            for (let i in resData) {
                let series = new Array(resData[i].CategoryName, resData[i].ProductName, resData[i].ProductSales);
                dataArray.push(series);
            }
            alert(dataArray);
            drawChart(dataArray);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Server couldnot process request');
        }
    });
});

function drawChart(resData) {
    $('#highchartData').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: "column"
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Product Sales for year 1997'
        },
        series: {
            data: resData
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: { enabled: true }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
            //categories: ['Beverages', 'Seafood', 'Dairy Products', 'Condiments', 'Meat/Poultry', 'Confections', 'Grains/Cereals', 'Produce']
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        }
    });
}
```

`alert(dataArray);` shows below data returned from controller's action

> Meat/Poultry,Alice Mutton,16580.85,Condiments,Aniseed Syrup,1724,Seafood,Boston Crab Meat,9796.33,Dairy Products,Camembert Pierrot,20652.28,Seafood,Carnarvon Tigers,15950,Beverages,Chai,4887,Beverages,Chang,7038.55,Beverages,Chartreuse verte,4475.7,Condiments,Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning,5214.88,Condiments,Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix,373.63,Confections,Chocolade,1282.01,Beverages,Côte de Blaye,46563.09,Seafood,Escargots de Bourgogne,2076.28,Grains/Cereals,Filo Mix,2068.15,Dairy Products,Flotemysost,9642.76,Dairy Products,Geitost,786,Condiments,Genen Shouyu,1474.83,Grains/Cereals,Gnocchi di nonna Alice,32604,Dairy Products,Gorgonzola Telino,7620.75,Condiments,Grandma's Boysenberry Spread,2500,Seafood,Gravad lax,629.2,Beverages,Guaraná Fantástica,1553.63,Dairy Products,Gudbrandsdalsost,14041.8,Condiments,Gula Malacca,6543.45,Confections,Gumbär Gummibärchen,11225.66,Grains/Cereals,Gustaf's Knäckebröd,4233.6,Seafood,Ikura,8819.5,Seafood,Inlagd Sill,6894.15,Beverages,Ipoh Coffee,11069.9,Seafood,Jack's New England Clam Chowder,4638.8,Seafood,Konbu,758.94,Beverages,Lakkalikööri,7883.1,Beverages,Laughing Lumberjack Lager,910,Produce,Longlife Tofu,888,Condiments,Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce,9331.08,Condiments,Louisiana Hot Spiced Okra,2958,Produce,Manjimup Dried Apples,23550.02,Dairy Products,Mascarpone Fabioli,2668.8,Confections,Maxilaku,3060.6,Meat/Poultry,Mishi Kobe Niku,6935.5,Dairy Products,Mozzarella di Giovanni,11838.6,Seafood,Nord-Ost Matjeshering,5884.29,Condiments,Northwoods Cranberry Sauce,4260,Confections,NuNuCa Nuß-Nougat-Creme,1551.9,Condiments,Original Frankfurter grüne Soße

Here i observed that data returned didn't have column names as

> {"CategoryName":"Meat/Poultry","ProductName":"Alice Mutton","ProductSales":16580.8500}

I can see the title given for column chart as 'Product Sales for year 1997' and also the options to print/ download chart. But the chart isn't shown. How to fix this and where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this line you define a format for the data:

> ```
> let series = new Array(resData[i].CategoryName, resData[i].ProductName, resData[i].ProductSales);
> ```

In Highcharts `data` is an array of points. Information about every point is grouped into an object or an array. It seems that you omit grouping and push all the properties from all the points into one array (which is not correct).

Refer to this **Docs page**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

It explains how to format your data properly before using it in the chart constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Kamil Kulig, actually my idea was to display all products. And products under same Category should display in same color.

As you said, I have removed `resData[i].CategoryName` from `Array` and now my array have only `ProductName` & `ProductSales` but that didn't even work.

Comment: See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/vz06ck8q/ It shows how to extract categories from your data and use a unique color for each of them.